# pi_tracker pirobot in Indigo?

Tags: ros, pi-tracker, ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i heard that pi_tracker (which using skeleton traking for humanoid robot) now is only available in Hydro. but, in the [website](http://www.pirobot.org/) they said there's available too for Indigo. so how about it? is it work?

what's the basic differences between hydro and indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220574/pi_tracker-pirobot-in-indigo?/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pi_tracker package was created a long time ago as an entry for the early ROS 3D contest.  I don't have plans to develop it in the future but I just now created an Indigo branch that differs from the Hydro branch only in the addition of default queue_size parameters for the ROS publishers in the two tracker nodes.

Note that the pi_tracker package depends on either the [openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker) package or the [skeleton_markers](http://wiki.ros.org/skeleton_markers) package (for which I just created an indigo-devel branch).  Under ROS Indigo, I have only had success using a Microsoft Kinect with these package.  It seems the Asus Xtion Pro Live can be difficult to get working with skeleton tracking on newer USB 3.0 machines and Ubuntu 14.04.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2015-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-11-30**:
Thanks patrick!